# Input validation security - no http:// or https:// allowed

Tags: php, string, validation

I try to do some basic validation. I want to make submitting links impossible.
I wrote some code that works semi fine. 
It doesn't work if `http://` or `https://` at the begining of the input

```
if(((stripos($message, "http://")) || (stripos($message, "https://"))) !== false)
    {
echo"Link is Here";
    }
else 
    {  
echo"Link is NOT Here";
    }
```

Is there are way to fix this problem. I use function **`stripos`** because I have to make sure `http://` and `https://` is case insensitive so I'm ok with all kind of trays like for example `HTTP://` or `hTTps://`

Comment: `if(stripos($message, "http://") > -1 || stripos($message, "https://") > -1)` or `if(preg_match('~^https?://~i', $message))`

Comment: `((stripos($message, "http://")) || (stripos($message, "https://")))` with `$message = 'hTTPs://foo.com'` is `false` because the statement is `false || 0` => `false !== false` => `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with your `if` statement. Change it to this:

```
if(stripos($message, "http://") !== false || stripos($message, "https://") !== false)
{
    echo "Link is here";
}
else 
{  
    echo "Link is NOT here";
}
```